# GCD in different classes

Tags: ios, gcdasyncsocket

I have an app where on start it checks the user's position and then get the weather for that spot. Mainly wind direction and speed.

It does the normal check to see it it has Intenet connection, but I found that if there is connection, but very slow the app freezes on launch screen (doing the check on startup).

I have a class that does this, which is called at startup after which a home screen is loaded.looking around, GCD seems the right way to go, but can I get the answer to be displayed in a label in the home screen when it is finished with getting the data? Main tread would have left, or rather bypassed that class and have arrived at the main screen.

Would I need to maybe use something like Notification Centre to help the label updating and re-load?

Thanks for any thoughts or code snippets.
Jorgen

PS. I am trying to keep the app iOS 5.1 to keep old iPads happy.

Comment: how do you check the internet connection? and why? on the latest WWDC every developer was encouraged to skip that part, and make network communication directly, and handle the _no-connection_ event in the `FALSE` branch of feedback, because methods of the _Reachability_ class are very slow.

Comment: I have a method that check that I can get to apple.com

Answer (score 0):

> GCD seems the right way to go, but can I get the answer to be displayed in a label in the home screen when it is finished with getting the data? Main tread would have left, or rather bypassed that class and have arrived at the main screen. Would I need to maybe use something like Notification Centre to help the label updating and re-load?

Yes, I think you're on a very good track here. Let's keep the two issues separate, though:

- After doing your background work, still in GCD, you're going to come back onto the main thread because you now want to update the interface. That's easy and straightforward.
- If you have a communication problem, a notification can be an excellent solution. You can broadcast the need to update that label, and *if* the correct view controller exists and is listening, it will get that information.

  Having said that, though, you should think about your architecture, since there may be a better way than a notification. Once you are back on the main thread, why are you not in a place where you have a way to *know* whether the correct view controller exist and to talk to it directly. I'm not saying the notification is bad/wrong! I've used this solution myself, and a notification is quite a standard way to come back from, say, an NSOperation. I'm just saying, give it a little thought.